# Visual Studio 2022 Rever poco is generating lots of empty lines

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 (Version 17.2.6) and Reverse Poco Generator (6.2.0) to apply database modifications on my code. But I got an issue, and I don't know how to fix it. While using reverse poco, lots of empty lines are inserted (see picture). I never had the issue before, but I can't find why is it creating those lines :/

Any ideas ?

[image: Screenshot of empty lines]

[image: Screenshot of changes]

Comment: Is this Simon Hughes's Extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimonHughes.EntityFrameworkReversePOCOGenerator)? If so have you raised an issue with him? The latest version is 3.6.1 so you probably want to upgrade first.

Comment: Have you considered moving to EF Core as EF6 is no longer being actively developed? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/efcore-and-ef6/#ef6

Comment: yes, the problem is that I can't switch to EF Core at the moment, because of other dependencies